# SQLite for joined tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

How would I convert the following statement from MySQL-ese to SQLite-ese?

```
UPDATE Attribute, Name 
  SET Attribute.AttValue = 'foobar'
  WHERE Attribute.NameID = Name.NameID 
    AND Name.Name = 'rotate_ccw'
```

It looks like SQLite doesn't support joins in an [UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

Comment: Correct.  FWIW, multi-table UPDATE is not standard SQL.  MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server both support multi-table UPDATE as an extension to SQL, but I don't think any other flavor of SQL does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE Attribute
  SET Attribute.AttValue = 'foobar'
  WHERE Attribute.NameID = (SELECT Name.NameID FROM Name WHERE Name.Name = 'rotate_ccw')
```